# Sacar fecha convertida en SQL con getdate

Tags: sql-server

Tengo esta consulta `SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-6,GETDATE())` la cual ahorita me retorna *"2021-11-25 19:17:48"*

Necesito que esa fecha que me regresó, la regrese con este formato: *"25 de noviembre del 2021"*

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, utilicé este pequeño comando

```
SET LANGUAGE spanish
declare @Fecha datetime
Set @Fecha=(SELECT dateadd(day,-6,GETDATE()))
SELECT DATENAME(DAY,@Fecha) + ' de ' + DATENAME(MONTH,@Fecha) + ' del ' + DATENAME(YEAR,@Fecha)
```

Me regresa *"26 de Noviembre del 2021"*

Dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le sirve. Saludos!